# Wireframe texture not rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, wireframe

I tried to make a texture with a wireframe but noticed the wireframe texture doesn't render. It acts like it's not there. How can I fix this?
[.blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/d42ccf22b46242c7860eed37400adeae)

[image: node tree 1/2]
[image: node tree 2/2]
[image: what should render]
[image: what renders]

Answer (score 0):

you put the wireframe in the roughness...if you wanna really "see" the wireframe, plug it in the shader...or in a colorramp:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the wireframe in the roughness to create that sort of pattern, im not trying to get those solid lines. I replaced the wireframe with a brick texture and that worked, idk why wireframe doesn't.